# Onto Group Homomorphism S3 to K4

Tags: abstract-algebra

Problem: Determine if there exists an onto group homomorphism 
$\alpha: S_3 \rightarrow K_4$ (the Klein Group)  Let K be the kernel of alpha.

Here is what I have so far: Since any onto homomorphism can be uniquely factored as $\alpha = \beta\sigma$ where $\sigma : G \rightarrow G/K$ and $\beta : G/K \rightarrow H$ where $\beta$ is one-to-one and $\sigma$ is onto then in this case $\beta $ would have to be onto as well, meaning that there would need to be four distinct cosets of $S_3$ which has 6 elements as there are four elements in K4, which is not possible, therefore there does not exist such a homomorphism.

Is this reasoning correct? What Can I say about the kernel of alpha??

Comment: Just use the fact that such an isomorphism would have $K_4 = S_3/\ker \alpha$, and compare cardinalities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no integer you can divide 6 by to get 4.